# How to add a different model with login functionality in keystonejs?

Tags: authentication, keystonejs

I am using KeystoneJS 0.3.19 to build an application that allows users to login and access all the application functionalities. The application needs to separate categories of users with slightly different user models since their are different functionalities supported for each type. I looked through many files that deal with user model definition, user creation, login and signin, and made some changes. Server runs fine and at the time of running website on localhost most of the code that I've changed goes through as well until in encounters persist function in *keystone/lib/session.js* where I wanted to put in a condition to see the type of user making the request and assigning appropriate value to a variable to use. I used *req.user, req.body.user* to determine this, both of which are clearly wrong since it's undefined at runtime.

The files I've changed are:

```
keystone/admin/api/session/signin.js

keystone/lib/session.js

keystone.js, to list the model in Admin UI

keystone.js/templates/views/signin.jade, select the type of user for login
```

My method of determining the usertype for *persist* function is wrong, what is the right method?

What other things I need to do to get this outcome?

I've already created the new model and it's being reflected on the Admin UI as I checked before this error occurred with session.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure am I get what you want to achieve but, as for me I extended User model for field (I'm using Keystone 0.4 jFYI)

```
accessLevel: {
  type: Types.Select,
  label: "Access level",
  index: true,
  numeric: true,
  options: [
    { value: 1, label: "admin" },
    { value: 2, label: "cool_user" },
    { value: 3, label: "soopa_user" }
  ]
}
```

So next you can check user accessLevel from code (I'm using pug engine)

```
if user && user.accessLevel == 2
  do something cool
```

And another option, you can extend existing User model for Reltionship field to model, which is consist of desired fields, actions, so on and work with that ref field next in your code